# Bootstrap: Fill remaining vertical space with responsive 24-column row

Tags: css, flexbox, bootstrap-5

This is my first question here, although I have been finding solutions on this site for several years though!

I feel this "multi-row" problem hasn't been addressed yet, at least I haven't been finding an answer for it.

I have a layout problem with CSS / HTML, using Bootstrap 5.3. I have two rows that need to span across the whole container (so almost the whole viewport).
My first row uses `flex-grow: 1!important; min-height: 0; overflow: hidden;` to grow - which works fine on wide enough screens. On small screens though, I stretch the content through 24 columns across two displayed "subrows". And then my lower "subrow" gets too long because it still uses the height of the whole row to calculate its height.

This is my simplified Code - please see the result in full window, otherwise it will look very messy:

```css
#root {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: .25rem;
}
.growing-row-overflow-hidden {
    flex-grow: 1!important;
    min-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.pianoroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.notYetReady {
    opacity: .5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="root">
<div class="container-md text-center border h-100">
    <div class="App h-100 d-flex flex-column">
        <div class="row growing-row-overflow-hidden">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="row h-100">
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-12 flex-grow-1 list-group p-2 ">
                        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary text-uppercase">Record</div>
                        <div class="list-group-item h-100"><button
                                class="btn btn-outline-success w-100 h-100">Start</button></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-12 flex-grow-1 list-group p-2 notYetReady">
                        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary text-uppercase">Stop</div>
                        <div class="list-group-item h-100"><button
                                class="btn btn-outline-warning w-100 h-100">Stop</button></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4 col-sm-12 flex-grow-1 list-group p-2 ">
                        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary text-uppercase">Save</div>
                        <div class="list-group-item h-100"><button
                                class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100 h-100">Save</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 list-group p-2 h-100 ">
                <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary text-uppercase">Your Pitch</div>
                <div class="list-group-item h-100 overflow-auto">
                    <div class="pianoroll">
                        <div style="height: 2000px; background-color: red">A lot of content...</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col list-group list-group-horizontal p-2">
                <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary text-uppercase">Sensitivity</div>
                <div class="list-group-item w-100 d-flex"><span class="flex-fill"><input type="range"
                            class="form-range liveSensitivitySlider" style="--inputRMS:0%;"></span></div>
                <div class="list-group-item"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100 h-100">Settings</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am open to realising this layout differently. My aim is to have the two rows to fill the whole screen - both on small screens in three displayed rows as well as on larger screens in two displayed rows.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Walle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to solve this myself using a responsive **CSS grid**.
If anyone has the same kind of problem, I recommend not using the rows as they don't seem right for this task (to fill the remaining vertical space but not more, even if the contained columns break over several lines and have a lot of content).
I had to add some classes for the layout of the buttons without rows and columns, but that were just little design fixes.

This is my solution:

```css
#root {
    height: 100vh;
    padding: .25rem;
}
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid: auto 1fr auto / 1fr 1fr;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.grid-left-or-top {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3;
    overflow: auto;
}
.grid-right-or-bottom {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 3;
    overflow: auto;
}
.grid-footer {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 3 / 3;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .grid-left-or-top {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    }
    .grid-right-or-bottom {
        grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
    }
    .list-group-vertical-md {
        flex-direction: column!important;
    }
    .list-group-vertical-md>.list-group-item:first-child:not(:last-child) {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0!important;
        border-top-right-radius: var(--bs-list-group-border-radius)!important;
    }
    .list-group-vertical-md>.list-group-item+.list-group-item {
        border-top-width: 0!important;
        border-left-width: var(--bs-list-group-border-width)!important;
    }
    .list-group-vertical-md>.list-group-item:last-child:not(:first-child) {
        border-top-right-radius: 0!important;
        border-bottom-left-radius: var(--bs-list-group-border-radius)!important;
    }
}
.pianoroll {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.notYetReady {
    opacity: .5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="root">
    <div class="container-md text-center border h-100">
        <div class="App h-100 grid-container">
            <div class="grid-left-or-top">
                <div class="h-100 w-100">
                    <div class="h-100 w-100 list-group list-group-horizontal list-group-vertical-md p-2 ">
                        <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary group-header">Record</div>
                        <div class="list-group-item flex-fill"><button
                                class="btn btn-outline-success w-100 h-100">Start</button></div>
                        <div class="list-group-item flex-fill"><button
                                class="btn btn-outline-warning w-100 h-100">Stop</button></div>
                        <div class="list-group-item flex-fill"><button
                                class="btn btn-outline-primary w-100 h-100">Save</button></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-right-or-bottom">
                <div class="list-group p-2 h-100 w-100 ">
                    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary group-header">Your Pitch</div>
                    <div class="list-group-item h-100 overflow-auto">
                        <div class="pianoroll">
                            <div style="height: 2000px; background-color: red">A lot of content...</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-footer">
                <div class="col list-group list-group-horizontal p-2">
                    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary group-header">Sensitivity</div>
                    <div class="list-group-item w-100 d-flex"><span class="flex-fill"><input type="range" min="-50"
                                max="0" step="1" class="form-range liveSensitivitySlider" value="-40"
                                style="--inputRMS:0%;"></span></div>
                    <div class="list-group-item"><button class="btn btn-outline-warning w-100 h-100">Settings</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```